# SFMC Journey Builder: Facebook Ad Audience activity not configuring properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ad-studio

In a journey I'm building i want to push entries into two advertising audiences: 1) Google Audience and 2) Facebook Audience. The Google Audience activity is set up and seems to be fine. However, when I try to configure the FB Ad Audience activity, the following bug occurs:

1. I configure the activity by filling out the overlay as shown on the screenshot.
2. Upon clicking 'done', the 'loading' icon appears and the Audience is created in Advertising Studio as expected.
3. When it's done loading, the activity returns to the blank state as shown in the screenshot. As if it was never configured.
4. When I re-enter the details using the same audience name, I get an error message saying that the audience already exists - which makes sense because it did generate in Advertising Studio.

I'm left without a working activity.

Solutions tried:

- Saving/validating/reloading the journey
- Relogging into SFMC
- Disabling all Chrome extensions
- Removing the created Ad Audience and retrying

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this before I'll contact Salesforce support?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Journey Builder Screenshot - marked activity is not working]

Answer (score 2):

Once you drag an ad audience activity to the canvas, set it up, and put spend behind the ad, the journey must be ACTIVATED before the FB audience can populate contacts. This is also true with ad campaign activities.

Why? Marketing Cloud requires at least 20 FB matches before it can create an audience.

How does it work? It takes the contacts in your entry event (data extension, cloud page, API, etc), hashes your 1st party data, and sends it to FB. FB tries to find matches based on the customer's email address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That makes sense, however, I'm unable to activate the journey because the FB Ad Audience activity stays 'unconfigured' after the audience is created.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?